# Is there some easy use image processing/editing library for Cocoa?

Tags: image, cocoa, opencv

Like OpenCV

I hope the library can do several simple image edit operation, like DrawLine(UiImage, startPoint, endPoint), or ConvertToGray(UiImage)

Answer (score 1):

**[`CoreImage`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Image)** is the built-in image manipulation library in Cocoa.

For example: [What is the best Core Image filter to produce black and white effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030631/what-is-the-best-core-image-filter-to-produce-black-and-white-effects)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using OpenCV , which is a great algorithms and image processing library. 
Choosing Opencv would give you more future option.

Try [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is not meant for image editing. You can do that, but it's like buying a big track to carry your groceries from the market.

The best way to do it is to look into some already integrated image editing libraries. And as I know, in Cocoa there are several of them. CoreImage, mentioned by Dor, is one of them.

And there are some specialized image editing / UI toolkits that may help you better than OpenCV. You may check whether ImageMagik or QT are available for Mac/iOS