# Why is my UIImage rotated after I edit its pixels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I scoured SO and some web tutorials to get this `IBAction` together that edits the pixels of an UIImage. The edit it supposed to make the photo greyscale, but it also rotates the image too, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone else spot the reason? Thanks!

```
- (IBAction)grayscale:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self.workingImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    _text1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", width];
    _text2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", height];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    int byteIndex = 0;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
    {
        int outputColor = (rawData[byteIndex] + rawData[byteIndex+1] +
                           rawData[byteIndex+2]) / 3;

        rawData[byteIndex] = (char) (outputColor);
        rawData[byteIndex+1] = (char) (outputColor);
        rawData[byteIndex+2] = (char) (outputColor);

        byteIndex += 4;
    }


    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGContextRelease(ctx);  

    self.workingImage = rawImage;  
    [_theImage setImage:_workingImage];
    free(rawData);
}
```

Comment: check your image orientation:  UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
If it is not 1 you might want to rotate it first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... orient = 1! Can you please tell me how to rotate it?

Comment: I tried just orienting the UIImageView using `imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2); `, and this shows the picture in the correct orientation, but my picture is now squished to landscape instead of its original portrait!

Answer (score 0):

That's how I "fix" image orientation:

```
- (UIImage*) fixImageOrientation:(UIImage *)image {

    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat aWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);;
    CGFloat aHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, aWidth, aHeight);

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;

    switch(orient)
    {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Invalid image orientation");

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft)
    {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -aHeight, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -aHeight);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, aWidth, aHeight), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

HTH

Comment: P.S.: and you are aware that there are easier methods to create a grayscale image than looping through pixels? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403939/making-a-uiimageview-grey

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I am definitely aware, this is just a proof of concept so that I am free to apply other transformative algorithms to the pixels.