# UIImage renderingMode coloured icon -> grey scale on UIAlertView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I have a multi-coloured image in a `UIBarButtonItem`. When I display a `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet`, I would like to turn it black and white.

I have played around with the different `UIImageRenderingModes` but none of them work for me. The only way I can get it to go gray-scale is if the whole image gets the UIWindow `tintColor` as a mask, which I don't want. I'd like to retain all the colours and then convert to grey scale when a `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet` appears.

I have seen this achieved in WhatsApp where the image of a contact in the navigation bar is coloured, and when you tap to see the `UIActionSheet` it turns grey scale.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10033772/3319153 ?

Hope that will help

Comment: It's not so much an issue converting it to grey scale, it's more regarding how to change it out when a UIActionSheet or UIAlertView appears.

Comment: You can work with their delegate : `– willPresentAlertView:` or `– willPresentActionSheet:`

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks! Please post your answer below and I'll accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rendering black and white :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033772/3319153

to handle ActionSheet or UIAlertView event, you can work with their delegate : `– willPresentAlertView:` or `– willPresentActionSheet:`

Answer (score 1):

write self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

Comment: This worked for me only i had to set it on the uiimageview