# Making a Black & White only camera with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I make a black&white camera with `UIImagePickerController`? Is there another way to produce a camera app without using `UIImagePickerController`?

Is there another way without using a filter? I want the camera to be black&white while the user is trying to take a photo.

Comment: The [GPUImage Framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [AVFoundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureDevice/defaultDeviceWithMediaType:). Few sample code is also available which will help you for better understanding.

please check **Managing White Balance** section for it. It will help you for implementation. 
Please let me know if you are still facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIImagePickerController` as usual but just apply a black and white filter to the image when it is taken. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030631/what-is-the-best-core-image-filter-to-produce-black-and-white-effects)

Comment: Is there another way without using a filter? E.g. I want the camera to show black&white while the user is trying to take a photo.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't really clear from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to take picture without using `UIImagePickerController` and use custom `filters` with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to make it Black&White.