# CIFilter how to turn white imageView.image with transparency to any color

Tags: ios, cifilter

I am trying to turn white imageView.image into different colors programmatically. The outlines are currently white.

I am trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030631/what-is-the-best-core-image-filter-to-produce-black-and-white-effects) with CIFilter but the images don't appear at all.

Here is the pasted code for reference:

```
- (UIImage *) filterImage: (CIImage *)beginImage color: (UIColor *) color{

     CIImage *output = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], @"inputColor", [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:color], nil].outputImage;

     CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
     CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
     UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage];

     CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

     return newImage;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, readwrite, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;


@end
```

**Solution .m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NJDLv"].CGImage];



    self.imgView.image = [self filterImage:inputImage color:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}

- (UIImage *) filterImage: (CIImage *)beginImage color: (UIColor *) color{

    CIColor *ciColor = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:color.CGColor];

    CIImage *output = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome"
                                 keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,
                       @"inputIntensity",@(1.0),
                       @"inputColor", ciColor, nil].outputImage;

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgiimage = [context createCGImage:output fromRect:output.extent];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgiimage];

    CGImageRelease(cgiimage);

    return newImage;

}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That still didn't work for me. The image remains white.

Comment: The input image has to have transparency set on.

Comment: I have added the screenshot with input and output using the method in the answer.

Comment: How do you set transparency on?

Comment: You have to use a graphic software like a gimp.

Comment: If that worked for you do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me. I am trying to manupulate the white into different colors. Is that maybe why?